# Factorization of 1d Ising model partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, ising-model, partition-function, spin-models

If I'm studying a 1-dimensional Ising model such that $\mathcal H = \sum_k J_k\sigma_k\sigma_{k+1}$, where $$J_k=\begin{cases}J&k \in2\mathbb N\\2J&k\in2\mathbb N+1 \end{cases}$$ can I initially impose periodic boundary condition in order to have $k\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$
$$Z=\sum_{\{\sigma\}}e^{-\beta \mathcal H}=\lim _{n\to +\infty}\sum_{\sigma\in\{\pm 1\}}\prod_{k\text{ even}}e^{-\beta J\sigma_{k}\sigma_{k+1}}\prod_{k\text{ odd}}e^{-2\beta J\sigma_k\sigma_{k+1}}\\=
\sum_{\omega_0=\pm 1}\dots\sum_{\omega_{n-1}=\pm 1}\prod_{k\text{ even}}e^{-\beta J\omega_{k}\omega_{k+1}}\prod_{k\text{ odd}}e^{-2\beta J\omega_k\omega_{k+1}}$$
and use transfer matrices:
$$Z=\lim_{n\to+\infty}Tr\left\{\left(\begin{pmatrix}e^{-\beta J}&e^{\beta J}\\e^{\beta J}&e^{-\beta J} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2\beta J}&e^{2\beta J}\\e^{2\beta J}&e^{-2\beta J} \end{pmatrix}\right)^n\right\}\\=\lim_{n\to +\infty}Tr\left\{\begin{pmatrix}e^{-3\beta J}+e^{3\beta J}&e^{\beta J}+e^{-\beta J}\\e^{\beta J}+e^{-\beta J}&e^{-3\beta J}+e^{3\beta J} \end{pmatrix}^n\right\}(?)$$

Comment: Sure, if you then change variables to $\tau_i = \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}$… But the easiest way is probably to impose free b.c. and sum over the spins one at a time (i.e. sum over $\sigma_n$, then $\sigma_{n-1}$, etc.). Each sum yields an explicit factor depending on the parity of the spin, but independent of the values of the remaining spins…

Comment: Maybe this might be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/553523/273635 (especially the answer to the question)

Comment: @YvanVelenik I added the details. PS I can't believe I received an answer from the professor who wrote the book I'm using to study statistical mechanics... Really honored and happy.

Comment: Yes, your approach should work. You can compare the result (in the thermodynamic limit) with the approach I suggested above. It is explained in more details (slightly differently) in the third approach described in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66727). PS: I am glad to hear you're learning from our book.

Comment: (I should add that your approach is much better than the one I suggest when  a magnetic field term is present, since it generalizes easily to this case...)